# How to pass two vars from one controller into one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want this two methods pass to one view :

```
public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> getProfitSum()
{
    var profBalance = db.Profits
                        .Where(x => x.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.IdUser.UserId)
                        .Select(x => new ProfitAndCostViewModel { ProfitSum = x.Sum(y => y.Value) })
                        .ToList();
    return profBalance;
}

public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> getCostSum()
{
    var costBalance = db.Costs
                        .Where(x => x.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.IdUser.UserId)
                        .Select(x => new ProfitAndCostViewModel { CostSum = x.Sum(y => y.Value) })
                        .ToList();
    return costBalance;
}
```

in my  ActionResult I Have this:

```
ProfitAndCostViewModel pcv = new ProfitAndCostViewModel();
            pcv.ProfModel =getProfitSum();
            pcv.CostModel =getCostSum();

             return View(pcv);
```

And in ProfitAndCostViewModel code is this:

```
public double ProfitSum { get; set; }
        public double CostSum { get; set; }
        public double FinalBalance { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> ProfModel { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> CostModel { get; set; }
```

this is the error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WHFM.ViewModels.ProfitAndCostViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WHFM.ViewModels.ProfitAndCostViewModel]'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a view model which has them both;

```
public class BigViewModel
{
    public List<ProfitsModel> ProfModel { get; set; }
    public List<CostsModel> CostModel { get; set; }
}
```

And controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    BigViewModel model =  new BigViewModel();
    model.costBalance = db.Costs...;
    model.profBalance = db.Profits...;

    return View(model)
}
```

Comment: thanks , but what is costBalance in your example , because in my is a var costBalance = db.Costs
   .Where(x => x.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
   .GroupBy(x => x.IdUser.UserId)
   .Select(x => new ProfitAndCostViewModel { CostSum = x.Sum(y => y.Value) })
   .ToList(); is this

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your parameters into a ViewModel or use a ViewBag